# How can I start a bash login shell in jenkins pipeline (formerly known as workflow)?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am just starting to convert my Jenkins jobs into the new Jenkins Pipeline(workflow) tool, and I'm having trouble getting the `sh` command to use a bash login shell.

I've tried

```
sh '''
#!/bin/bash -l
echo $0
'''
```

but the `echo $0` command is always being executed in an interactive shell, rather than a bash login shell.

Comment: She-bang should be in the first line of the script: 
sh '''#!/bin/bash -l
echo $0
'''

Comment: @izzekil is right!!!! UGH.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

@izzekil is right!!!! Thank you so much!

So to elaborate a little bit about what is going on.  I used `sh` with `'''` , which indicates a multiple line script.  HOWEVER, the resulting shell script that gets dumped on to the jenkins node will be one line down, rather then the first line. So I was able to fix this with this

```
sh '''#!/bin/bash -l
echo $0
# more stuff I needed to do,
# like use rvm, which doesn't work with shell, it needs bash.
'''
```

Comment: You should be able to get rid of the sh ''' (and ending ''').

Comment: @gaoithe , can you please provide an example of what you mean?

Comment: just have #!/bin/bash as first line in job config. I've tried to explain better in the answer edit.

Comment: @gaoithe, those lines are needed, this isn't the execute shell job, this is using Jenkins pipeline, so this is a Jenkins job written in groovy.

Comment: Ahhh. Okay. Thanks. I understand. Doh! Whoops.

Comment: Is there a way to specify the shell for the entire Jenkinsfile instead of each and every invocation of the 'sh' command?